# Serialize and Deserialize Date between ASP.Net MVC and ExtJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, serialization, extjs

I've been searching through the web to look for a solution for this but still stuck.

I'm having difficulties serializing DateTime object. The standard serialize using DataContract will give this result /Date(1262600239000)/. After Ext.encode the result changed to /Date(1262600239000)/. The result from Ext.encode is not readable in ExtJS date related components such as DateField and ColumnModel for date.

As for deserializing, i'd have to provide the date in this /Date(1262600239000)/ format in order to deserialize the date. How can i achive this with the ExtJS DateField?

Is there any specific ways to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/rymoore/serializing-net-dates-into-json-for-extjs-26016)?

It's an override for ExtJS' JSON encode and decode methods. Make sure to read the last comment as well.

Comment: i've tried this method and it works... but it gives another problem... The Ext.decode decodes my tree json incorrectly... As for reference this is my post in ExtJS Forum

http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=424408#post424408

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Newtonsoft Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/). It's open source and free (MIT license).

It is the one used by the [Ext.Direct .NET Router](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?68161-Ext.Direct-.NET-Router) which was developed by Evant (who is part of ExtJS Core Development Team).

You can see this code that uses it for a DateTime in the **sample of Ext.Direct .NET Router**:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Company {
    //...
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "started")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime Started { get; set; }
    //...
}
```