# ASP.net MVC - Model with DateTime, trying to serialize for Json() for jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, datetime, serialization, jqgrid

I've got a model...

```
    [DataContract]
    public class DeviceModel
    {
        [DataMember(Order=1)]
        public string Alias { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public string RatePlan { get; set; }

        public DeviceModel()
        {
            Alias = null;
            Location = null;
            State = null;
            DateCreated = null;
            RatePlan = null;
        }
    }
```

This model contains a DateTime object, as you can see.  I am using this model as the data for the jqGrid plugin we are using.  The only issue is, the DateCreated field shows "/Date(1285128000000)/" when the Grid loads, instead of the readable date.  I've read some of the other posts here, but I don't feel that they quite fit the bill for what I'm looking for.  I'm looking for a way to format this DateTime field to a human readable string?  Suggestions?

Comment: There are different ways to solve your problem: either on the server side on on the client side. Could you appemd your question with 1) definition of the jqGrid 2) code example which shows how exactly you serialize the data on the server side before sending it back to the client. 3) Contain `DateTime` values only the date or the date  & time information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON knows only two primitive datatypes: strings and numbers and no `Date` type. Data Contract Serializer supports [more types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx). For example `DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset`, `TimeSpan`, `Guid`, `Uri`, `XmlQualifiedName`. If you send data to the client which use also Data Contract Serializer to deserialize the data you can use any from the datatypes without any problems.

The most simple solution of your problem is preparing the data on the server before sending the data. If you will serialize only objects which has only strings and numbers as properties or arrays/`IList<T>` then you will has no problem. For example, per default jqGrid wait the data in the **ISO Date format**: `Y-m-d` with numbers for `Y`, `m` and `d`. If you convert your data on the server to the Y-m-d format and use `formatter:'date'` in the corresponding `colModel` definition your problem will be solved.

You can also solve the problem on the client side using of the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) and the [custom unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm gonna check into using the Custom Formatter, but I figured handling the data on the server side was going to be the way to fix this.  Thanks again!

Comment: @DavidAndroidDev: Just now I posted (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/sopport-for-microsoft-date-format-date1285128000000/#p19945) a suggestion for a small modification of the jqGrid code to support Microsoft serialization format for the `DateTime` type: "/Date(1285128000000)/". Probably soon jqGrid will sopport it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Newtonsoft Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/) as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011035/serialize-and-deserialize-date-between-asp-net-mvc-and-extjs/3731486#3731486)