# using jquery jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have created a sample project in asp .net mvc using vs 2010. In my solution structure I have got the default jquery files that were added by vs. I am trying to use jQuery grid. So I searched in the web to see for a suitable plug in. But I could not find one. It would be of great help to recommend some references on jQuery jqgrid usage and the necessary javasript files that need to added to the solution structure

Comment: Have you looked at the jqGrid wiki? There's an extensive samples and documentation on their site

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your comment. Yes the wiki looks good. I can start from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835957/jquery-with-asp-net-mvc-calling-ajax-enabled-web-service/2836817#2836817), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912008/jqgrid-does-not-populate-with-data/3914796#3914796) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078592/sortable-jqgrid-using-linq-to-mysql-dblinq-and-dynamic-linq-orderby-doesnt-w/4079121#4079121).

Answer (score 0):

I think the [jgrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs) and [demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) will be a great place to start.

As far as the files are concerned, you can start by adding the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and `ui.jqgrid.css` files available in the [jqgrid destribution](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).