# Problem binding jqGrid in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I am new to using jqGrid and jquery.I am not able to bind my json data which I retrive from the webmethod onto the jqGrid.

I have also used firebug to cross verify and i am receiving data from it. Some help regarding this will be great. I would aslo like to know if any other references needs to be added.

following is the code that I have implemented.

PAGE METHOD

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData()
{
    Customer Cone = new Customer();
    Customer Ctwo = new Customer();
    Cone.CustomerID = "100";
    Cone.CustomerName = "abc";
    Ctwo.CustomerID = "101";
    Ctwo.CustomerName = "xyz";
    List<Customer> lstCustomer = new List<Customer>();
    lstCustomer.Add(Ctwo);
    lstCustomer.Add(Cone);
    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerz = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string serializedData = jsonSerz.Serialize(lstCustomer);
    return serializedData; 
}
```

client side coding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetData() {
        alert('Inside GetData');
        var data = PageMethods.GetData(OnSuccess, OnFailed);
    }
    function OnFailed(error) {
        alert('Failed');
        alert(error.get_message());
    }
    function OnSuccess(data) {
            alert(data);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            alert('Button Clicked');
            $('#list').jqGrid({
                url: 'http://localhost:1405/WebSite1/Default.aspx/GetData',
                data: '{}',  // For empty input data use "{}",
                dataType: 'local',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                colNames: ['CustomerID', 'CustomerName'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'CustomerID', index: 'CustomerID', width: 80,
                      align: 'left', editable: false },
                    { name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName', width: 120,
                      align: 'left', editable: true}],
                pager: $('#pager'),
                rowNum: 5,
                rowList: [10],
                sortname: 'CustomerID',
                sortorder: 'desc',
                viewrecords: true,
                width: 300
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

AND HTML code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Fetch" title="Fetch"
       onclick="javascript:GetData()" />
<table id="list">
</table>
<div id="pager">   
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all I recommend you to play a little with another working code which you can download [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WebServicesPostToJqGrid.zip) (see more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029909/load-data-from-webservice-asmx-to-jqgrid-please-help-me/4031603#4031603)). More links to another examples you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561697/using-jquery-jqgrid/4570070#4570070).

I try to describe some problems in your current code.

1. You use 'http://localhost:1405/WebSite1/Default.aspx/GetData' as the url. You shold better use only pathes like '/WebSite1/Default.aspx/GetData' or 'WebSite1/Default.aspx/GetData' or you can easy receive [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem.
2. You should use ASMX service instead of placing the code inside of ASPX page (Default.aspx/GetData). You should just add new item to your ASP.NET solution and choose Web Serice template. The corresponding code template will be added for you and web.config will be modified. In the same way you can place WCF service inside your ASP.NET project. The step is independ on the technology which you use (WebForms, ASP.NET MVC and so on).
3. Instead of manual JSON serialisation with respect of `JavaScriptSerializer` you should define `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attriute to your method and return an object from the web method (like `List<Customer>` in your case). The JSON serialization *will be done automatically* for you.
4. You use `dataType: 'local'` which is wrong parameter for jqGrid. Correct parameter will be `datatype:'json'` (`datatype` instead of `dataType` and 'json' to make the request to the server).
5. Instead of `type: 'POST'` you should use [mtype: 'POST'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options).
6. Instead of `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` you should use `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }`.
7. The usage of `data: '{}'` is also wrong. Probably you try to use `data` parameter of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like with `dataType` parameter. In jqGrid you should use `pastData` instead of `data` and the `data` parameter must be an array and has another meaning. I recommand you to look at the code of the example (see reference at the begin of my answer).
8. You should not place `$('#list').jqGrid({...});` inside of `click` handle. The problem is that the code make some initializations of jqgrid and then fill the grid. What you probaly want is creating the grid only once and then refreshing it with another input data probaby (I am not sure that it is so). So you should move `$('#list').jqGrid({...});` inside of `$(document).ready(function() {...};`. If needed you can use `$('#list').trigger("reloadGrid")` inside of the `click` event handle. Alternatively you can use [GridUnload](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) to destroy the existing grid before creating it new.

I can continue, but my main recommendation is to examine another examples and use ASMX or WCF service which provide the data for jqGrid.

Comment: I agree with oleg, there is no need to manually serialize the collection. Page method do it auto for you. If i am correct it does by default to Json Format

Answer (score 0):

Entire grid binding event is called before your page method.
You have put it under document.Ready event. Try calling it from the button click event.

I am not sure but there should be some way to bind json data to Jquery grid on client side without using the URL part.

try mapping "data:" to some Json value.