# How to implement JQgrid in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have worked with JQgrid in asp.net mvc, but now i am trying to implement this in asp.net.
I find a hard time making a JQgrid sample in asp.net.

Do i have to use the JSON response in asp.net or i have to implement this in any other way.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't full understand your requirements. ASP.NET MVC is also ASP.NET application. Do you have restriction to .NET version? Do you can use only some specific .NET technology?

In general you can mix the main code of your size with the code in other ASP.NET technology. For example WCF service can be the part of ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Form application. The main code can provide the user interface of your web site and the WFC service will provide JSON data for any Ajax requests from jqGrid.

So you can just use any examples of WCF, ASMX Web Service or even simple ASHX handler.

[The demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInWebForm.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666711/315935) shows how to use ASHX handler in ASP.NET Web Form application.

[Another demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WfcToJqGrid.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3914796/315935) shows how to use WCF service.

[The demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestWebApplicationWithjqGrid.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296601/315935) or [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WebServicesPostToJqGrid.zip) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4593474/315935) demonstrate the usage of ASMX web services.

Comment: @balanv: You are welcome! What technology you would use: WCF, ASMX Web Service or ASHX handler?

Comment: @Oleg , can you suggest some link or starting point examples for using jqgrid with web forms , ashx examples will do , thanks a lot.

Comment: @freebird: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInWebForm.zip) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7666711/315935) uses ASHX handler in ASP.NET Web Form application. I included the link in my answer.  [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridInWebForm1.zip) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258377/315935) uses ASHX handler in ASP.NET Web Form application too.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for that I will try , but does the ashx example includes stored procedure also ?

Comment: @freebird: It doesn't matter whether to use STORED PROCEDURES or not. It's concerns mostly the *technology which you uses for the database access*. If you would define Entity using STORED PROCEDURES or if you would uses `SqlCommand` with `SqlDataReader` you can use STORED PROCEDURES without any restrictions.