# jQGrid display inline edit delete cancel buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am using jQuery Grid plugin(jQGrid) and i am wondering how could I achieve such behavior with jQGrid inline Edit Actions like on that sample http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/EditRowInlineActionIcons 
Currently i setup my jQGrid with pager with edit actions:

```
 .navGrid('#pager', { view: false, edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false });
```

but i want to have inline Edit Actions like in the sample above, may be some one did something like 
that.

[image: Inline Edit Actions]

Need help.

**UPDATE:**

I put the property `editactioniconscolumn: true`  but still din't get the Edit Actions

```
colNames: ['Id', 'FName', 'LName'],
colModel: [{ hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true },
{ name: 'FName', index: 'FName', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true, editactioniconscolumn: true },
{ name: 'LName', index: 'LName', width: 50, align: 'left', editable: true, editactioniconscolumn: true }]
```

Comment: @Vasya: On the very same page, there is a description on how to enable the edit/delete/cancel buttons .. ` Just add a column anywhere you wish and set it EditActionIconsColumn property to true - this will enable automatic Edit/Save/Cancel buttons that will trigger the corresponding actions and events` .. Did you see that?

Comment: @Cybernate see my update, and i am not using HtmlHelper i am using just jQgrid jquery plugin

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793) which includes [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm). Is it what you need?

Comment: By the way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) you will find one more way to archive almost the same, but with respect of very simple custom formatter and `beforeSelectRow` or `onCellSelect` event handler. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellClick.htm)

Comment: @Oleg thanks, looks like it is what i need here http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ActionButtons.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have moved my answer to the following thread

[ASP.Net MVC 3 JQGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092866/asp-net-mvc-3-jqgrid/13166722#13166722)

I think it will be seen more there.  It answers questions in both threads.   It is the only comprehensive jqGrid ASP.NET MVC 3 I have found on the web that describes how to implement full CRUD functionality.

I did not repeat the post here to avoid duplicating content.