# How can a list of objects (a part of a bigger Model) with with Add and Delete buttons in MVC be updated with AJAX calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The situation is as follows:

1. I have a ViewModel that has a property that's a `List<Product>`, where `Product` is a class with let's say properties `Property1`, `Property2` and `Property3`.
2. I have to render the ViewModel and I wish to render the `List<Product>` in an HTML table each row of which  has a "**Delete**" button for that row.
3. Underneath the afore-mentioned HTML table, there should be 2 buttons:

   3.1 "**Add**" - used to add a new empty `Product` to the list

   3.2 "**Use default product list**" - the List has to be loaded via an AJAX call to the `GetDefaultProduct()` action of the controller
4. Clicking on a "**Delete**", "**Add**" or "**Use default product list**" button should not post the entire page
5. The model contains some other lists of items as well - for the sake of example: `List<Sales>`, `List<Orders>` and so on. I'm hoping I can re-use the solution for the List for those lists as well.

Is there a way to do this with ASP.NET MVC?
If yes, what is the best way to do it with ASP.NET MVC?

I did this with jQuery templating and I managed to implement this with simple operations, but I have to do it in an  ASP MVC solution and I'm still trying to get the hang of the technology.
I've been reading about the `Editor` template, `RenderAction`, `Async` action and partial views and I'm trying to compose a solution with them and I'll post it if it works.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and comments!

**UPDATE**

The solution lies (as Darin pointed out) in [Steve Sanderson's blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).
However, it assumes that the reader is aware of under-the-covers way of how a List of objects should be rendered in a CRUD-friendly, indexed manner.

So, in order to help anyone who wants to have an indexed list of omplex objects, I suggest reading mr. Haacked's blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx.

After you are done with it, you can move on to Sanderson's blog. By the way, take a good look at the `BeginCollectionItem` custom HTML helper - its implementation isn't a trivial one as one might think.
The demo project is a sight for sore  eyes - it's spot on and easy to understand.
The proposed solution DOES use some `jQuery.ajax()` calls (for the **Add** link), but just out of bare necessity.

PS: It's a bit frustrating that one has to read an explicit article from one of the developers of ASP.NET in order to find out that there's an implicit CoC (Convention-over-Configuration) in the default model binder - it just knows how to work with Lists, but no out-of-the-box HTML helper (or anything similar) doesn't let you in on this.

Personally I think that CRUD-friendly rendering of `List<object>` is a very common scenario, not an edge case so it should be simpler to use and a part of the ASP.NET MVC out-of-the-box machinery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you reading the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). It would definitely put you on the right track for implementing an editing scenario of a variable length list.

Comment: thanks a ton, mate! I'll update the question with the notes that I got while I investigated Steve's blog post and demo. I don't like the fact that he relies on magic strings, but the article got me enough details so I managed to find some more articles and thus the successful solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy way of doing it if you want to do using Jquery.

[ASP.Net MVC 3 JQGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092866/asp-net-mvc-3-jqgrid)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - the JQGrid looks awesome :)
However my goal is to stick to vanilla out-of-the-box MVC3 without any 3rd party bits (and as little jQuery as possible - I love jQuery, but the task demands otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself some pain and download the [Telerik Extensions for ASP.Net MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx). It's open source ( though there's a paid option).

The Grid control (possibly in conjunction with the Window control) will give you all the UI functionality you need and there's plenty of online examples.

I've been doing a lot of master-detail UI work recently and Telerik's been an immense help.

Comment: Hi Steve and thanks for the suggestion. However, I'm trying to implement a solution with just vanilla ASP.NET MVC code and with minimal use of any sort of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the answer you are looking for, but hey, try to create a default typed edit view for a model using folowing settings:

[image]

```
this will generate the folowing code for view (assuming Razor engine):

    @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.User>

@{
    View.Title = "GetData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>GetData</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Description
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The code wich will handle edit/update/details will accept Id of the entity as a parameter. These are paricualr other methods of your controller which will handle editting/adding/previewing of you item

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately my scenario is more complex and (as I now understand) performing AJAX updates on a List of objects, which is just one property of a bigger model, which in turn has several more properties which are also lists. Performing CRUD operations on such a list (as Steve Sanderson pointed out in his blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)) requires some not-so-trivial code.