# Linq To Entities - OrderBy

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, linq-to-entities, entity

I am following Phil Haacks tutorial on using JQGrid with ASP.Net MVC. My application is ASP.Net MVC 3 using Entity Framework 4.

I have the following code to perform the sorting and paging for my data which is returned to the JQGrid

```
var query = equipService.GetAllEquipment().AsQueryable()
                .OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord)
                .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);
```

However, this code creates an error at the .OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord) line. The error is

```
System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TKey>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

The query is calling a method, GetAllEquipment(), in my service layer which looks like this

```
public List<Equipment> GetAllEquipment()
    {
        List<Equipment> equipList = new List<Equipment>();
        equipList = equipRepository.GetAllEquipment();

        return equipList;
    }
```

This method, then calls the same name of method in my repository, like so

```
public List<Equipment> GetAllEquipment()
    {
        var query = (from e in Data.DBEntities.Equipments
                     select e).ToList();

        return query;
    }
```

I can kind of solve the problem by creating an instance of my objectcontext in my controller method and use this code

```
using (AssetEntities context = new AssetEntities())
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = context.Equipments.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);


            var query = context.Equipments
              .OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord)
              .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
              .Take(pageSize);

        }
```

However, I don't really want to do this, rather I would like to keep to the repository pattern I use throughout my application for all database interaction.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks as ever everyone.

Comment: `.OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord)` is *not* dynamic LINQ syntax. It's ESQL / QueryBuilder syntax. Do you know which method you're calling?

Comment: @Craig: I had to download the Dynamic Query Library as stated here weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/…, then reference System.Linq.Dynamic at the top of my contorller. My code now works :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommed you to use `PropertyInfo`, `GetProperty` or `FieldInfo`, `GetField` depend on your data model. In the case you can implement `OrderBy` operation without any extensions. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078592/sortable-jqgrid-using-linq-to-mysql-dblinq-and-dynamic-linq-orderby-doesnt-w/4079121#4079121) for details.

**UPDATED**: I reread your question carefully one more time. It seems to me, that your problem is inside of `GetAllEquipment` method. It returns `List<Equipment>` and not `IQueryable<Equipment>`. So the `GetAllEquipment` method get "SELECT * FROM it.Equipment" and return the data as a `List` which are **no more Entity**. With `equipService.GetAllEquipment().AsQueryable()` you will have `IQueryable<Equipment>` object, but you will not more use LINQ to Entity and so you should **not use** "it." prefix before the names.

Comment: @Oleg. I updated my repository and service classes to return IQueryable<Equipment>. I also took out the "it." out of my OrderBy clause. My query now looks like this var query = equipService.GetEquipment()
                    .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
                    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
But the same error still exists.

Comment: No, my code still isnt working Oleg. I am still getting the error on .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)

Comment: @Oleg: If i change my query to this...var query = equipService.GetEquipment()
                    .OrderBy(e => e.equipmentID)
                    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
This works. So it looks as if my problem is the dynamic OrderBy clause I am using...

Comment: @tgriffiths: Do you tried to use `GetProperty` to implement ordering of data like I did in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078592/sortable-jqgrid-using-linq-to-mysql-dblinq-and-dynamic-linq-orderby-doesnt-w/4079121#4079121?

Comment: @Oleg: I finally worked it out. I had to download the Dynamic Query Library as stated here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx, then reference System.Linq.Dynamic at the top of my contorller. My code now works :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tgriffiths: I am glad to hear, that your program works now, but in case that you use Entity Framework you **don't need** `Dynamic Query Library`. I downloaded Phil Haacks tutorial, made some minimal bug fixing and modifications, replaced LINQ to SQL to Entity Framework, **removed System.Linq.Dynamic** and all work without any problem. I don't know what problem exist in your code, but you can download Phil Haack's demo after my modification from http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/JQueryGridGemo.zip and verify that it works.

Comment: @Oleg: I think this might explain why I had to use Dynamic Query Language http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140809/linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: @tgriffiths: Your problem is that you try to mix LINQ to Entities and Entity SQL queries (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896238.aspx)). The `Data.DBEntities.Equipments` object is `ObjectQuery<Equipment>` if support `IQueryable<Equipment>`, but in other SQL dialect: [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx). Probably I don't commented my last demo enough. In your example it means, that you just should use **directly** `Data.DBEntities.Equipments` instead of `equipService.GetAllEquipment().AsQueryable()` and all will work.

Comment: @tgriffiths: The `ObjectQuery<Equipment>` has the method `OrderBy(string)` method (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358828.aspx)) and LINQ To SQL **not has** (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.orderby.aspx)). So it you stay by LINQ to Entities you can implement all what you need for jqGrid **without System.Linq.Dynamic**.

Answer (score 1):

Your repository is terribly wrong. It always load all data from db to application and performs paging and sorting in web server's memory. That is a big difference to your last query which executes both sorting and paging in db and returns only data for one page. If you want to create query in controller both repository and service must return IQueryable and they mustn't call ToList. Calling ToList executes current query.

Comment: I changed both my service and repository methods to return IQueryable<Equipment>, and then changed the call in my controller to IQueryable<Equipment> query = equipService.GetEquipment()
                    .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
                    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);

Comment: However, I still have the same error as mentioned above. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using some special Linq extenssions like Dynamic Linq? Because common OrderBy doesn't allow specifying ordering as string.

Comment: Yes, I am using Dynamic Linq, as you can see from the following line .OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord) I am concatenating strings together.