# LINQ Dynamic Query Library

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I am building an ASP.Net MVC 3 application with Entity Framework 4. When the two pieces of code below are executed, both variables (query1 and query2) have a return type of

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Asset.Model.Equipment>
```

Query1 uses a direct instance of the ObjectContext, however, Query2 uses a repository pattern, ie, it calls GetEquipment in EquipmentService, which in turns calls the same named method in Equipment Repository. Both the methods in the Service and Repository return

```
IQueryable<Equipment>
```

How, here's my question, how come query2 will only work when I include

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
```

At the top of my controller

```
using (AssetEntities context = new AssetEntities())
        {
            var query1 = context.Equipments
            .OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord)
            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);
        }


        var query2 = equipService.GetEquipment()
            .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);
```

If I omitt System.Linq.Dynamic from my controller, I get an error within Query2 at

```
.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
```

Which states

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TKey>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

Does anyone know why query1 can work without having to use System.Linq.Dynamic, but that query2 needs it to execute?

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first query `context.Equipments` has type `ObjectQuery<Equipment>`. The `ObjectQuery<T>` has the method [OrderBy(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358828.aspx) which one need for `.OrderBy("it." + sidx + " " + sord)`. So the first query work.

In the second query you use `equipService.GetEquipment()` of the type `IQueryable<Equipment>`. The `IQueryable<T>` has only extension method [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.orderby.aspx) with `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` as the parameter instead of `string`. So to use `OrderBy` with `IQueryable<Equipment>` you have to write something like

```
equipService.GetEquipment().OrderBy(e => e.equipmentID)
```

but it is not what you can use. To you need another extension method, which can provide you the LINQ Dynamic Query Library in form `System.Linq.Dynamic`.

In many cases LINQ to Entities has [many restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx), but in your case it has more advantages as LINQ to SQL. So I recommend you to stay by LINQ to Entities in your case. I am sure that in the way you will receive better performance because of native support of all function directly in the Entity Framework which you use.

Because LINQ to Entities or `ObjectQuery<Equipment>` supports `Where(string)` method (to be exactly [ObjectQuery.Where(string predicate, params ObjectParameter[] parameters)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx) method) you can relatively easy implement filtering/searching in jqGrid. The usage of `.Where` can be

```
.Where("it.equipmentID < 100")
```

or

```
.Where("it.equipmentID < @maxId", new ObjectParameter ("maxId", 100))
```

for example (the usage of "maxId" instead of "@maxId" in the `ObjectParameter` is not typing error).

**UPDATED**: In "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) you can find [the example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemo.zip) which shows how to implement filtering/searching in jqGrid based on the idea which I described above.

Comment: @tgriffiths: In [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) I show how to implement filtering/searching in jqGrid which can be used for both [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) and [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching). I updated my answer with the corresponding links.

Answer (score 4):

"it" is the default [ObjectQuery.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347374.aspx) property value. In fact, when you are using the first query, you perform an implicit Entity SQL Order By clause, while in the second one you are using LINQ to Entities, and it needs System.Linq.Dynamic namespace to work correctly.