# Linq Expression for Paging / Pagination with dynamic OrderBy

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0, pagination, entity-framework-4.1

All,

I am trying to get paging working with a grid.  In order to do this, I have to pass in which field to sort by.  I cannot figure out how to do this with a Linq query.  I am using .NET 4 / EF 4.1.  In the two examples below, #1 works just fine.  The problem is, I am passing in the field to sort by, and so I need to be able to dynamically change what we are sorting by.  When I try to use a string as in example 2, it does not sort by my expression.  Is there any way to accomplish this?  It seems like lots of people should need this functionality.

```
    [Example 1]
(from e in _context.MyEntity
 where (MyWhereClause)
 orderby e.SomeProperty Ascending
 select e).Skip(Offset).Take(MyCountPerPage);

    [Example 2]
(from e in _context.MyEntity
 where (MyWhereClause)
 orderby "SomeField, ASC"
 select e).Skip(Offset).Take(MyCountPerPage);
```

-Thanks-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to pull your orderby out of the query and use the extension method version,

```
var query = from e in _context.MyEntity
            where (MyWhereClause)
            select e;

query = query.DynamicOrderBy("property");

query = query.Skip(Offset).Take(MyCountPerPage);
```

Next, we have to build the `DynamicOrderBy`, I'm assuming the query is against some sort of `IQueryable<T>`.

```
//Need this to construct the query correctly
static MethodInfo s_orderBy = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "OrderBy");

static IOrderedQueryable<T> DynamicOrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string property)
{
    var expr = source.Expression;
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    var sortExpr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(p, propInfo), p)
    var method = s_orderBy.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), propInfo.PropertyType);
    var call = Expression.Call(method, expr, sortExpr);
    var newQuery = source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(call);
    return newQuery as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that you need this for jqGrid. I posted before [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) with the full [VS2008 project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemo.zip) which you can use as an example.

The main idea is that Entity Framwork can be used with `ObjectQuery<T>` which supports sorting like "SomeField, ASC" which you need. So you are able implement all you need **without** Dynamic LINQ extension. Even more (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140809/linq-dynamic-query-library/5158477#5158477)) you can use construction like

```
.Where("it.equipmentID < @maxId", new ObjectParameter ("maxId", 100))
```

with the WHERE having string arguments ("it.equipmentID < @maxId"). So you can implement all paging, sorting and filtering using string arguments, which you need for jqGrid. The example from which I started my answer demonstrate how you can do this.

Answer (score -2):

```
   var query = (from e in _context.MyEntity
     where (MyWhereClause)
     orderby e.SomeProperty Ascending
     select e).Skip(Offset).Take(MyCountPerPage);

    if(Ascendingflag)
       query = query.OrderBy(a = > SortExpression);
    else
       query = query.OrderByDescending(a = > SortExpression);
```