# jgGrid not getting populated by WCF Rest service call

Tags: jquery, wcf, rest, jqgrid

I am new to jQuery and jqGrid. I have written following code to call a WCF RESTful service and populate a jqGrid. Though the call to WCF RESTful service returns a json output, jqGrid for some reason is not able to interpret this output.

IService Interface:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Employees", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "GET")]
      List<Employee> GetCollection();
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace="")]
    public class Employee
    {
      [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "empId", Order = 1)]
      public string EmpId { get; set; }
      [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "empName", Order = 2)]
      public string EmpName { get; set; }
      [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "dob", Order = 3)]
      public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
      [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "department", Order = 4)]
      public string Department { get; set; }

    }
```

Service Implementation:

```
    public List<Employee> GetCollection()
    {           
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.EmpId = "1";
        emp.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime("21/03/1979");
        emp.EmpName = "Haris";
        emp.Department = "HR";
        empList.Add(emp);

        return empList;            

    }
```

JQuery Script:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
        $("#jQGrid").html("<table id=\"list\"></table><div id=\"page\"></div>");
          jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url:'http://localhost:9002/SampleServices/Service/REST/Employees',
            //datastr: mystr,
            data: "{}",  // For empty input data use "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            colNames: ['Emp Id.', 'Emp Name', 'DOB', 'Department'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'empId', index: 'empId', width: 90, sortable: true },
            { name: 'empName', index: 'empName', width: 130, sortable: false },
            { name: 'dob', index: 'dob', width: 100, sortable: false },
            { name: 'department', index: 'department', width: 180, sortable: false }
            ],
            multiselect: false,
            paging: true,
            rowNum: 1,
            rowList: [1, 5, 10],
            pager: $("#page"),
            loadonce: true,
            caption: "Employee Details",
            success: successFunction
          }).navGrid('#page', { edit: false, add: false, del: false }
        );
    });
```

Call to 
        "http://localhost:9002/SampleServices/Service/REST/Employees "
returns the following:
        [{"empId":"1","empName":"Haris","dob":"/Date(290851200000-0700)/","department":"HR"}]

Developers could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current code have a lot of errors. The most important error is the usage of imagination names of jqGrid options. You should examine [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) and use the options and [callbacks](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) which are really supported. Just some examples: you use currently `data`, `dataType`, `type` and `contentType` options exist in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The corresponding jqGrid options should be `postData`, `datatype`, `mtype` and `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json"}`. You should additionally use `serializeGridData: function (postData) { return JSON.stringify(postData); }`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3914796/315935) for more details.

To be able to read the date in the format `"/Date(290851200000-0700)/"` you need use `formatter: "date"`. The most important thing which you need to include in jqGrid is the [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) which corresponds the data which you use.

So the corresponding code should be about the following:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $("#jQGrid").html("<table id=\"list\"></table><div id=\"page\"></div>");
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "HarisFarooqui.json",
        datatype: "json",
        height: "auto",
        jsonReader: {
            root: function (obj) {
                return obj;
            },
            repeatitems: false
        },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        colNames: ['Emp Id.', 'Emp Name', 'DOB', 'Department'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'empId', width: 90, sortable: true, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'empName', width: 130, sortable: false },
            { name: 'dob', width: 100, formatter: "date", sortable: false },
            { name: 'department', width: 180, sortable: false }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 30, 1000],
        loadonce: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        gridview: true,
        pager: "#page",
        caption: "Employee Details"
    });
});
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/HarisFarooqui.htm)

[image]