# Is it possible to add an hyperlink at the bottom of a jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, hyperlink

[image: this is how my grid looks]I have a JQgrid which cotains only one column which contains some 4 values... I need to add a constant hyperlink after that 4 values which is independent of the values in the cell.. It should not be a combined with column... Instead it should appear as an separate hyperlink inside the JQgrid below the column.. How to achieve this??

This is my code:

Aspx:

```
<table id="UsersGrid" width = "750px">

     </table>
```

Js:

```
$(function () {
            $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid({

                datatype: function (pdata) { getData(pdata); },
                colNames: ['CampaignName'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'campaign_name', index: 'CampaignName', width: 750},
                    ],
                    hidegrid: false,
                caption: 'Recent Campaigns'

            });
});

 function getData(pData) {
            var userid = $("#userId").val();
            var postData = {};
            postData.userId = userid;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/iSpaceWeb/CampaignService.svc/GetRecentCampaigns",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: postData,
                success: function (data) {
                    ReceivedClientData(JSON.parse(data));
                },
                error: function (data, textStatus) {
                    alert('An error has occured retrieving data!');
                }
            });
        }

        function ReceivedClientData(data) {
            var thegrid = $("#UsersGrid");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                thegrid.jqGrid('addRowData', i, data[i]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is this hyperlink constant, or depends on cell value?

Comment: And why can the hyperlink not appear in it's own cell inside the grid?

Comment: @Kasyx It is a constant hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `footerrow: true` as one more option of jqGrid which includes footer row. To fill the row you can use `footerData`:

```
$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
    campaign_name: "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>"
}, false);
```

Moreover I don't recommend you to use `datatype` as function and to use `addRowData` to fill the data. It's very bad style. Instead of that you can use `datatype: "json"` and set additional options of the Ajax request using `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" }` and `serializeGridData`.

The call of `JSON.parse(data)` inside of `success` of `$.ajax` having `dataType: "json"` looks **very suspected**. I suppose that you convert the returned object inside of `CampaignService.svc/GetRecentCampaigns` *manually* to JSON string. It's wrong. You should return *object* and WCF runtime converts the returned data * automatically* to JSON string. You current code makes serialization to JSON **twice**, so you have to parse the server response also twice: once it will be parsed by `$.ajax` having `dataType: "json"` and one more time you parse it by calling `JSON.parse(data)` explicitly. You should fix the problem in your server code and remove after that unneeded call `JSON.parse(data)` from the client side.

Comment: Actually its getting bisected and i am getting a lines between column values and the hyperlink..How to avoid that?

Comment: @Xavier: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you post picture and describe in other words the problem?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my JQgrid.. Please check that in my edit

Comment: @Xavier: It seems that you use wrong `width` of the grid or the `width: 750` for the column. Try to increase the value to have no scroll bar. I recommend you additionally add `height: "auto"` option to jqGrid. To tell the trust the whole construct of usage `datatype` as function is very bad. Look at [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3914796/315935) which contains base code of usage WCF with jqGrid.

Comment: @Xavier: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Xavier.htm). About so can look the client part of your code.

Comment: It worked.. Thank you.. And thanks for the link describing WCF with jqgrid.. Really useful