# How to Dynamically add Column and Row Header and based on the Row and Column value how to bind Data in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I need to dynamically render the jqGrid. I am using WCF Rest service to get the Data from the CRM Database. As far as i have statically gave the Column header in column name and column model will bind the data.

Now my requirement is Column header and Row Header needs to be generated dynamically.
Based on the column and row value each cell value has to be shown.
I am sending the data as `DataTable` from the service.
I am not sure how to bind the data in jqGrid.

Please anyone give your input.

My sample `DataTable` which is returned from WCF Service

```js
<DataTable xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="LTC" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="LTC">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="vc_longtermcondition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="vc_longtermconditionid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <DocumentElement xmlns="">
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>Asthma</vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>91c0c30c-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018</vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>Chronic Heart Failure</vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>dbe68618-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018</vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>CKD</vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          dde68618-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC4" msdata:rowOrder="3" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          COPD
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          e94f4222-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC5" msdata:rowOrder="4" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          Diabetes Type 1
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          e1b54c29-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC6" msdata:rowOrder="5" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          Diabetes Type 2
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          2b86ad32-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC7" msdata:rowOrder="6" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          Hypertension
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          d1d7c339-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC8" msdata:rowOrder="7" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          LTC10
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          df1dbcd1-c977-e111-ac35-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC9" msdata:rowOrder="8" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          LTC11
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          40f5deda-c977-e111-ac35-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC10" msdata:rowOrder="9" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          LTC12
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          42f5deda-c977-e111-ac35-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC11" msdata:rowOrder="10" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          LTC8
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          fe5e3ecb-c977-e111-ac35-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
      <LTC diffgr:id="LTC12" msdata:rowOrder="11" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <vc_longtermcondition>
          LTC9
        </vc_longtermcondition>
        <vc_longtermconditionid>
          005f3ecb-c977-e111-ac35-005056a50018
        </vc_longtermconditionid>
      </LTC>
    </DocumentElement>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

Here vc_longtermcondition will be the ColumnHeader(Asthma,Diabetes,COPD)
and vc_longtermconditionid will the cell value respective to the columnheader

MySampleGrid will be like this

```
id ----------- Asthma -------------------------ChronicHeartFailure------------------
1.    91c0c30c-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018     dbe68618-816e-e111-a207-005056a50018
```

Comment: You should append the text of your question with an example of JSON data (at least two rows of data) returned from WCF service. The description "I am sending the data as DataTable" isn't clear enough.

Comment: By the way you can use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer/Chrome/Firefox (press F12 to start) or free tools like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to trace the HTTP traffic.

Comment: You are welcome! You should click "edit" link (button) below your question and *modify the text*. You should append the text with exact JSON data example. jqGrid is unable to read any common JSON data and to display it as a grid, but one can specify `jsonReader` parameter and `colModel` so that the data will be read (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data)). So you should first post the exact JSON data and then one can help you.

Comment: Hi Oleg.I have updated my question.

Comment: Web browsers don't contains common XML parser. You should convert the output data to JSON instead of XML. One can use the standard `System.ServiceModel.Web` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3914796/315935)) or to use any other JSON serializer (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3079326/315935) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3131413/315935)).